# JQuery mobile load external script

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, external

I have the following page in a jQuery mobile site:

```
<div data-role="page" id="myPage">
   <script type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script>
   <script src="https://someexternalscript.js"></script>
</div>
```

The first script tag, with the script contained in it, is evaluated properly. Every time I navigate to the page, an alert is shown. The second script tag however, is only evaluated when I navigate the browser directly to this page. When I navigate through the site itself, it isn't being evaluated.
I noticed with Fiddler that the source is being downloaded, it just doesn't seem to be evaluated.

Any ideas what could be causing this, and how it could be resovled?

Comment: Isn't that what the page role is about? Only show /run the stuff defined within the page?

Comment: That's fair enough. But in my case the javascript actually defines (most of) the content of the page. And I can't really change that because it's a third-party product.

Comment: Late, but I just answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941859/uncaught-referenceerror-using-external-script-jquery-mobile/24942517#24942517

Answer (score 1):

script tag is is not self closing tag, so you need to close it using `</script>`

Comment: Ah yes, little mistake when writing  this question. My code did have it closed properly. So that's not it :)

Comment: @PJanssen well i thought that was the problem, but other problem might be same domain origin problem as you can not load different domain content

Comment: I have considered that too. But then why would it work fine when I refresh the page or navigate there directly with the browser?

Comment: @PJanssen that the policy dude...you can access it from same domain but from other domain you need some `auth_tokens`

Comment: I'm not navigating to the location of the javascript, but to the location of the page. So it's still loading from a different domain, and working! But only when navigating directly to the specific page through the browser.