# Uncaught ReferenceError using external script & jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a web app but can't get my javascript to work.

When loading the page with a fresh started browser I get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: getResult is not defined' (is located in js/ajax.js) but when I refresh the page everything works. I have tried to move where the script loading takes place but I can't get it to work.

I found a bunch of similar questions but they seem to suggest to load script inside  and to not use $(document).ready() and I am doing that already. Anyone?

**EDIT:**
*I noticed that the error only occurs when going from another jQuery mobile page.*

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sio.signalare.se</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" /> 
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .wrap {
            white-space: normal !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a class="ui-btn-left" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="back"
        data-iconpos="notext" href="../"></a>

        <h1>ATC-felkoder</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
            <li>
                <h2 class="wrap">F1</h2>
                <p class="wrap"><strong id="F1-result"></strong></p>
                <select id="F1" onchange="getResult(this);">
                    <option value="" selected>Välj</option>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="E">E</option>
                    <option value="F">F</option>
                    <option value="H">H</option>
                    <option value="L">L</option>
                    <option value="P">P</option>
                    <option value="U">U</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <h6>Version 2.0</h6>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

**js/ajax.js**

```
function getResult(e) {
    if (e.value) {
        var ajax_load = "<img src='img/loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
        var loadUrl = "data/result.php?args=" + e.id + "|" + e.value;
        $("#" + e.id + "-result").load(loadUrl);
    } else {
        $("#" + e.id + "-result").empty();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Have you tried rearranging the files so that you call js/ajax.js AFTER jquery is called? You refer to a JQuery function ($) before JQuery is actually defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

;TLDR:  `<head>` is ignored on internal pages when using jQuery Mobile.

To use jQuery Mobile with external styles and scripts, you're going to have to load the same set of scripts and styles to every page, [per the documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html).

Comment: Thanks, Moving script into jquery content area made it load so I don't have to use it on every page.